# Matlab: Extracting Dates from a cell array

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab cell array whose members look like:

```
'abc201301.csv'
'avf201312.csv'
'sdffdsd201305.csv'
'wfeef201406.csv'
'ffgewgfw201106.csv'
'sdfdf201101.csv'
'wrrrt201009.csv'
```

I want to extract the following in a numerical matrix without using a for loop as this matrix is massive:

```
201301
201312
201305
201406
201106
201101
201009
```

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a partial solution for you. You can extract the numbers in the following way:

```
[~, remain] = strtok(str, ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']);
```

This will return to remain the number plus `.csv`, which is a constant length string that you should be able to eliminate directly by `remain = remain(1:end-4)`. The strtok function can also be called on a cell array of strings, but it will return a cell array result. In order to access the contents of a cell array without a for-loop, see this [Mathworks discussion](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/241826) for some ideas of syntax.

I'm sure there must be a way to get strtok to give you only the result you want (so you can skip removing the `.csv` part), so I recommend playing around with it yourself a little (and check out the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtok.html)).

Anyway, I know this isn't a complete answer, but hopefully this should give you the components you need for a full solution.

Comment: Yeah after that I used regexprep and cellfun with @str2num. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If `A` is your initial cell array,

```
B = regexpi(A,'\d{6}','match');
B = cellfun(@str2num,vertcat(B{:}));
```

should do the trick. It pulls out sequences of 6 numeric digits into separate cell arrays, and then converts them into a single array of numbers.